# How to insert current date into data base?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['enq']))
{

  extract($_POST);

 $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM enquires2 WHERE email = '".$email. "'");
 if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
  {
      echo '<script>alert("EmailId Already Exist Please Login with diffrent Id");</script>';
  }
 else
 {
 $enqq =  "insert into enquires2(name,email,phone,message,current_date)values('$name','$email','$phone','$message','$current_date')"; 
 $res_enqq = mysqli_query($link,$enqq);
 if($res_enqq)
  {
    if(isset($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!=""&&$_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"])
    {  
      echo '<script>alert("Your Enquiry Has Been Send. We May Contact You Soon ");</script>';

    }
    else
    {  
      echo '<script>alert("Validation Code Does Not Match Please Try Again");</script>';    
    } ?>
```

form:

```
<form method="post" action = 'index.php' onsubmit="return validateForm();" name="form">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" style="width: 74%; background: black;">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Id" name="email" style="width: 74%; background: black;">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" style="width: 74%; background: black;">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="39" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="background: black;"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="Put Text Here" style="margin-left: -100px; background: black;">
        <img src="captcha.php" style="margin-top: -7px;"/><br>
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" name="current_date" id="current_date"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function getDate()
      {
          var today = new Date();
          var dd = today.getDate();
          var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
          var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
          if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
          today = yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd;

          document.getElementById("current_date").value = today;
      }
      getDate();
      </script>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="submit" name="enq" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 215px; border-radius: 0px; margin-top: -80px;">
      </div>
</form>
```

how to insert current date into database when submit form data if I remove current date from insert query it will run but when I insert current date it shows nothing so. How could we do this?

Thank You

Comment: what is the type of `current_date`? `datetime` or `timestamp` or `date`?

Comment: You can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or NOW() in your sql query.

Comment: current_date type is Date

Comment: @samorten  `$date = date('Y-m-d');` use this `$date` into your query

Answer (score 1):

Use **NOW()** Or **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()**

```
$enqq =  "insert into enquires2(name,email,phone,message,current_date)values('$name','$email','$phone','$message',NOW())";
```

or

```
  $enqq =  "insert into enquires2(name,email,phone,message,current_date)values('$name','$email','$phone','$message',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
```

While creating a table you can use **current_date** field type as **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** so current date and time automatically inserted into the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try the above code:

```
$enqq =  "insert into enquires2(name,email,phone,message,current_date)
          values('$name','$email','$phone','$message','".date('Y-m-d')."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the **CURDATE()** function of MYSQL, it prints the date same as the functions of php and its easier:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp

Example:

`ennq = "INSERT INTO enquires2 (name, email, phone, message, current_date) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$phone."', '".$message."', CURDATE())";`